# Bootstrap modal not showing in asynchronous event

Tags: knockout.js, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-deferred

I have a viewmodel that rebinds itself in the case of a change of an id property

```
function ViewModel(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = ko.observable(data.selectedId);
    self.array = data.array;
    self.displayed = ko.observable(self.array.filter(function(i) {
        return i.id === id;
     })[0]);
    self.id.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        self.displayed(self.array.filter(function(i) {
            return i.id === newValue;
        })[0]);
    });
 }

 // $(document).ready
 $.ajax({...}).then(function(data) {
     ko.applyBinding(new ViewModel(data));
 });
```

problem is that the filtering of the array takes up some time. I've decided to show a Bootstrap modal window to make him wait.

I created a `<div class="modal">` etc... in my html that I displays a waiting message, and changed the code like this.

```
function ViewModel(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = ko.observable(data.selectedId);
    self.array = data.array;
    self.displayed = ko.observable(self.array.filter(function(i) {
        return i.id === id;
     })[0]);
    self.id.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        function promise() {
            var dfd;
            dfd = $.Deferred();
            dfd.resolve(newValue);
            return dfd.promise();
        }
        $('#mymodal').modal(); // (2)
        $.when(promise()).then(function(id) {
            return self.array.filter(function(i) {
                return i.id === id;
            })[0];
        }).then(function(object) {
            self.displayed(object);
        }).then(function() {
            $('#mymodal').modal('hide');
        });
    });
 }

 // $(document).ready
 $('#mymodal').modal(); // (1)
 $.ajax({...}).then(function(data) {
     ko.applyBinding(new ViewModel(data));
 }).then(function() {
     $('#mymodal').modal('hide');
 });
```

the first `(1)` case is working perfectly (on Internet Explorer), while the second one `(2)` is not. I also added a `.catch()` call at the end of each promise chain to ensure that it's not a problem of an uncaugh exception, but that wasn't the case.

Comment: What are the symptoms of it not working perfectly?

Comment: Presumably the `$.when()` etc is designed to allow the modal to be displayed before the processor-intensive filter commences? That approach is subtly different from a `setTimeout()`, which will be less expensive in itself and stand a better chance of meeting the objective.

Comment: As you are interested only in the 0th filtered element, try instead a `for()`  loop with a `break` to avoid the need to iterate beyond the first find. Performance isn't guaranteed to to improve, but certainly could.

Comment: 1) the title states that the modal is not showing up
2) how do you know how much time will it take to perform the searching?
3) filtering is not the real problem here, it's the knockout binding on the page that is slow. That's why the first time I create the ViewModel I wait for the ko.applyBindings method to return in order to hide the modal.

Comment: In that case, concentrate on point (2), which has most potential. The search time is irrelevant. What I'm suggesting is to push the search/binding/modal-hide downstream into a later event turn via a setTimeout *with zero delay*. That stands a better chance of allowing the modal to show than a promise-based approach.